# why to use " | safe" in jinja2 Python

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am following a Flask tutorial where he is using " | safe " in jinja2 template. Why do we need this pipe symbol and safe?

without using safe it prints all html tags.

By using `| safe`, it shows proper formatting.  Why does it work this way?

Below is the jinja2 code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <small>Written by {{article.author}} on {{article.create_date}}</small>
    <hr>
    <div>
        {{article.body | safe}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It would perhaps have been a better choice for it to be named `trusted` instead of `safe`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `| safe` Jinja2 will print symbols as they are in your variable, that means that it won't translate "dangerous" symbols into html entities (that Jinja2 does by default to escape "dangerous" ones). Use this option if you trust variable's content because in opposite case there can be vulnerabilities for example [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 5):

From the [DOCS](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#html-escaping):

> When generating HTML from templates, there’s always a risk that a variable will include characters that affect the resulting HTML. There are two approaches:
>
> - manually escaping each variable; or
> - automatically escaping everything by default.
>
> Jinja supports both.

In the *automatically escaping everything by default* mode, to mark content as safe, and therefore not in need of escaping, use the filter:

```
| safe
```

[Working with automatic escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping).