# Passing variable from flask to html adds &quot;

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to pass a variable from flask to my html code. I'm adding it as a url for a button, so a user can follow it. My problem is that the buttons don't work an when inspecting the website I see that the variables have had `&quot;` added to them. Removing this makes the buttons work.
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Testing buttons">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Test">
        <style>
            h1 {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #2f2d2d;
                text-align: Center;
            }
            p {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: Center;
                color: #2f2d2d;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <p>Click the buttons below to go to your results: </p>
    <button onclick={{ value1 }}>
    Yandex.com
    </body>
</html>
```

Value1 in my python code:

```
input1 = (str(""""window.location.href='""")
          + str(img_search_url) + str('''';"'''))
return render_template('results.html', value1=input1)
```

For testing purposes let `img_search_url` = `https://yandex.com/images/search?cbir_id=1865182%2F7z8tGw017Oxvkl-ZRGX7jA6207&amp;rpt=imageview&amp;lr=123432`

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why to use " | safe" in jinja2 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975383/why-to-use-safe-in-jinja2-python)

Comment: @fourjr I don't think so. I've had a look but I don't really understand it. Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `|safe` filter as mentioned on [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3206446/8129786).

```html
    <button onclick={{ value1|safe }}>
```

This ensures that the auto unescaping is turned off. If you do it on untrusted data, it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities though.